# codeigniter removing index.php (possible problem with host)

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter

Hi everyone I'm having some problems when removing index.php in CodeIgniter.

I created my application locally and it works fine but when I uploaded it, removing index.php doesn't seem to work.

I have a feeling this could have something to do with my host, it's not the best and I've had problems before. It's hosted on Fatcow.

So..

all my CodeIgniter files are located in a sub-dirctory called outfitr. e.g

```
<root>/outfitr/
```

I have my .htaccess file located in this folder with the following taken from the CI wiki:

**EDITED**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /outfitr/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

changes fo my config.php look like the following. I have enabled query strings as I need them for a section of my application.

```
$config['base_url'] = "<host>.com/outfitr/";
$config['index_page'] = "";

...

$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Any help would be great. As I said I think it might have something to do with the host Fatcow.

I have tested mod_rewrite, following the steps on the following page and it seems to be enabled.
[http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-test-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-t40.html](http://rewrite_test)

Answer (score 3):

ok so after some trial and error I finally got it working. I setup my .htaccess file as follows. Note the '?' in RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /outfitr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Then in config.php I set

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Think this is down to the way some hosts setup their mod_rewrite module. Dreamhost and hostgator have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

> 1. If your installation is not in the server root you will need to amend the RewriteBase line from “RewriteBase /” to “RewriteBase /folder/”

The current .htaccess you have is re-routing all requests to /index.php, which as you said yourself is not there. You want them to route to /outfitr/index.php.

You can do this by changing the RewriteBase /outfitr/

If not, please give more detail.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I've changed it as you suggested, but it now just directs all urls to the default controller. outfitr/testing/ will show the default controller, where as outfitr/index.php/testing/ loads the testing controller

Comment: try just /testing not /outfitr/testing